# JavaFX ToolKit Not Initialized

Tags: java

I'm trying to have two inputs for an admin username/password, but an error by the name of "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized". This program was working fine until I added the JTextField stuff, and I checked a ton of websites (Oracle, StackOverFlow, etc), and couldn't find an answer. I don't think I'm using JavaFX in my code anywhere. Thanks in advance :)
The full error code is at the bottom.

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
//import java.awt.*;
//import java.awt.event.*;
//import java.util.Scanner; Replaced with JOptionPane;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
//import java.io.File;                 
//import java.io.FileWriter;
//import java.io.FileReader; //Needed for a previous version
//import java.io.IOException;
//import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;   
import java.util.Date;
public class HackerGame {
public static void Credentials() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println('\u000C');
    String[] names = new String[]{"Hugh Jackman","David Lowe","Ethan Reed"};
    String[] usernames = new String[]{"HughMan13","BigDave13","Ethanol13"};
    String[] passwords = new String[]{"SmallMan31","SmallDave31","Diesel31"};
    System.out.println("Gathering Employee Information...");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
    System.out.println("Listing Employee Credentials: ");
    System.out.println(""); //Kept for distance purposes
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + names[i] + " Username: " +
                            usernames[i] + " Password: " + passwords[i]);
        System.out.println("---");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
}
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
}
public static void Growth() throws InterruptedException {
    int years = 2012;
    int value = 150000;
    System.out.println('\u000C');
    System.out.println("Company Growth By Year: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Year: " + (years + i) + " Value: " + "$" +
                            (value + (45000 * i)));
        System.out.println("---");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);                    
    }
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
}
public static void Console() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println('\u000C');
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println("Accessing Console Log For: " + dateFormat.format(date) + " ...");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
    System.out.println("---------------");
    System.out.println("IP 153.131.132.64 Connected");
    System.out.println("IP 153.131.132.64 Opened /bin/users/admin/username.txt");
    System.out.println("IP 153.131.132.64 Closed /bin/users/admin/username.txt");
    System.out.println("IP 153.131.132.64 Opened /bin/users/admin/password.txt");
    System.out.println("IP 153.131.132.64 Closed /bin/users/admin/password.txt");
    System.out.println("IP 153.131.132.64 Cleared /bin/console/cache");
    System.out.println("IP 153.131.132.64 Disconnected");
    System.out.println("IP 233.132.104.140 Connected");
    System.out.println("IP 233.132.104.140 Opened /bin/console/cache");
    System.out.println("IP 233.132.104.140 Restored /bin/console/cache");
    System.out.println("IP 233.132.104.140 Copied /bin/console/cache");
    System.out.println("IP 233.132.104.140 Closed /bin/console/cache");
    System.out.println("IP 233.132.104.140 Disconnected");
    System.out.println("End of Log For: " + dateFormat.format(date));
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println('\u000C');
    System.out.println("You are hacking into the system. Use these numbers to");
    System.out.println("help you: 33472001, 123, and 321. Good Luck.");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Loading Game...");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(7);     
    String[] firewallpass = new String[]{"33472001","10027433","20013347"};
    String[] firewallreq = new String[3];
        firewallreq[0] = "Enter First FireWall Password: ";
        firewallreq[1] = "Enter Second FireWall Password: ";
        firewallreq[2] = "Enter Third FireWall Password: ";
    String[] database = new String[]{"Employee Credentials","Company Growth","Console Log"};
    System.out.println('\u000C');
    String input;
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                ("Launch Program? Y/N: ");
    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
        System.out.println("Initializing...");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        System.out.println('\u000C');
    } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
        System.out.println("Exiting...");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        System.exit(0);            
    } else {
        System.out.println("Exiting...");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    //System.out.println(firewallreq[i]);
    String firewall; 
    firewall = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(firewallreq[i]);
    System.out.println('\u000C');
    if (firewall.equals(firewallpass[i])) {
        System.out.println("Bypassing...");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
    } else {
        System.out.println("You have been blocked. Exiting...");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
boolean adminLogIn = true;
while(adminLogIn) {
    System.out.println('\u000C');
    System.out.println("Enter Administrator Credentials: ");
    String adminusername = "admin";
    String adminpassword = "admin123";
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

    JTextField username = new JTextField();      
    JTextField password = new JTextField();
    Object[] message = {
        "Username: ", username,
        "Password: ", password
    };
    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Login", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        if (username.getText().equals(adminusername) && password.getText().equals(adminpassword)) {
            System.out.println("Logging In...");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            adminLogIn = false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong username/password. Try Again");
    }
}
}
    System.out.println('\u000C');
    boolean loggedIn = true;
    while(loggedIn) {
    System.out.println("Enter Q to logout");
    System.out.println("You have access to these databases: ");
    System.out.println("----------");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println(database[i]);
        System.out.println("----------");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
}
    boolean methodChoice = true;
    while(methodChoice) {
        String method;
    method = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter A Method: ");
if (method.equalsIgnoreCase(database[0])) {
    Credentials();
    methodChoice = false;
} else if (method.equalsIgnoreCase(database[1])) {
    Growth();
    methodChoice = false;
} else if (method.equalsIgnoreCase(database[2])) {
    Console();
    methodChoice = false;
} else if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
    System.out.println("Logging Out...");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
    System.exit(0);
} else {
    System.out.println("Enter A Valid Inquiry.");
}
}
}
}
}
```

And this is the exception

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized"
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:268)
at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:83)
at bluej.runtime.ExecServer.runOnTargetThread(ExecServer.java:902)
at bluej.runtime.ExecServer.access$700(ExecServer.java:78)
at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:767)
```

Comment: I run your program and no error occurred. Maybe provide complete stack trace of exception

Comment: Can you add the stack trace in question, please?

Comment: Swing constructors and methods may only be called from the AWT event dispatch thread.  When you violate that rule, you get unpredictable behavior.  That’s why it works for other people but not for you.  Use [EventQueue.invokeAndWait](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeAndWait-java.lang.Runnable-) to run Swing code on the proper thread.

Comment: @Piro I've added the full error at the bottom

Comment: @coder-croc I've added the full error at the bottom

Comment: @VGR Do you have any idea as to how I would be able to implement the EventQue.invokeAndWait into my program? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was that the application I was using, BlueJ, was corrupted in some way in that I wouldn't be able to run any of my programs. Re-Downloading and deleting the corrupted program fixed this issue. Thanks everyone for the help :)